# Where can I download older versions of elementary OS?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, luna

It looks like the team killed the old release downloads [on SourceForge](https://web.archive.org/web/20160201005339/http://sourceforge.net/projects/elementaryos/files/?source=navbar) and [their website](https://web.archive.org/web/20160220093000/https://old.elementary.io/). Where can I find copies of older versions of this libre, open source software?

Comment: Does freya work better than loki? Cuz I really have some problems with loki, it's lagging sometimes and it takes some time to power up.

Comment: @DariusAl. Superficially they're pretty much the same, except for maybe Ubuntu 14.04 vs. 16.04 for the underlying packages. It might be beneficial to "downgrade" if you have older/weird hardware that worked better with an older kernel, maybe. Freya will only get security updates from the Ubuntu repos until April 2019, so just be aware of that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please keep in mind that elementary supports its penultimate releases [only slightly into its current release's life](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8266/5565). The older software below is unsupported by the developers and is provided here primarily for purposes of history and curiosity.

---

A librarian once told me about the lifecycle of periodicals. At first, they are common, used, and after some time, they lose their currency and are discarded. Then they become rare and mainly curios for historians. Looks like we're nearing that latter half already.

So [the DistroWatch links](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=elementary) are down—elementary isn't hosting these anymore—and the major distro archives ([the Internet Archive distro collection](https://archive.org/details/linux_distributions) and http://distro.ibiblio.org) do not carry it. Until they do, the best way to get these will be by torrent. Be sure to check the torrents against their hashes to verify their authenticity by running the command below each section.

### Loki 0.4.1 (64-bit)

> sha256sum elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20180214.iso
> 5c499579e6ba05eed5626abbbb68fc1e3660e23ccb6a27f1a5f7794fed98bd56

magnet:?xt=urn:btih:54dca0477d74d88ed051a9cd62fe5359151e7823&dn=elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20180214.iso&tr=https%3A%2F%2Fashrise.com%3A443%2Fphoenix%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80%2Fannounce

### [Loki 0.4 (64-bit)](http://linuxtracker.org/index.php?page=torrent-details&id=535c241c5b14fdfe47bec6cbaac4a39cd41c719e)

> `sha256sum elementaryos-0.4-stable-amd64.20160921.iso`
> [`8035e0a2fbc977d931af22dcefb77ed6fe87815d89188a43e2cb345f13e629cf`](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#verify-your-download)

### [Freya 0.3.2 (64-bit)](http://linuxtracker.org/index.php?page=torrent-details&id=fce720af722a813a184c5550a924aaa60a8d9af1) [(32-bit)](http://linuxtracker.org/index.php?page=torrent-details&id=001b104e49d517cf7a41593a73c3861b7c8e34f8)

- [Softpedia](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Operating-Systems/Linux-Distributions/Elementary-OS-67717.shtml) also has a mirror of the latest Freya ISOs

> `sha256sum elementaryos-0.3.2-stable-amd64.20151209.iso`
> [`ee737ffa6bf33b742c5a7cee17aa26dec5ee3b573cbbc4b53cbe2a2513c9197a`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160416153313/http://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#verify-your-download)
>
> `sha256sum elementaryos-0.3.2-stable-i386.20151209.iso`
> [`97e143e762a1d1e3abac9eba33a59a7a6b9f319a7063cd47e406678c379fc683`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160416153313/http://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#verify-your-download)

### Luna 0.2

- Assorted mirrors: [unchecked torrent links](http://iso.linuxquestions.org/element/elementary-os-0.2/#torrent), [virtual panic](http://www.virtualpanic.com/isos/Linux/Elementary%20OS/2013/), [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9M1TKaD_dgIQWVWVzRqUUhLUkk/view), [simosnet-livecd](http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/simosnet-livecd/elementaryos/), [mirror](http://simosnet.com/livecd/elementaryos/), [ac.id](http://repo.unnes.ac.id/iso/elementaryos/)

> `sha256sum elementaryos-stable-amd64.20130810.iso`
> [`bfd2d56ec2936e7634f466372be6c839af12a8f7df956c0989664dcf9029da18`](https://web.archive.org/web/20130814121430/http://elementaryos.org/answers/what-are-the-checksums-for-the-elementary-luna-isos)
>
> `sha256sum elementaryos-stable-i386.20130810.iso`
> [`fb00edb0037e3ed6e4d15e035bd9e450e148c1aa18a15e26c839fb550e075051`](https://web.archive.org/web/20130814121430/http://elementaryos.org/answers/what-are-the-checksums-for-the-elementary-luna-isos)

### Jupiter (0.1) at [the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/ElementaryOs-Jupiter)

Remember: Lots of copies keeps stuff safe

Comment: Can you add Loki beta 2 download?  The stable release has a problem for some of us where it does not install GRUB and thus we're left needing the beta as it did install and boot just fine...

Comment: This is an excellent answer. All previous versions of elementary are listed along with numerous mirrors. Most importantly checksums are listed **along with a legitimate source**!

Comment: If you're looking for Freya, I don't think Softpedia is an option anymore. Their elementaryOS entry seems to have been updated to Loki. Try user22600's site below or virtualpanic.com.

Answer (score 6):

I have archived old versions of Elementary OS and I published them online: http://osarchive.sda1.eu/elementary-os

Comment: thank you to user22600 for having the download available for the 32 bit version. my computer wouldn't take the 64, so will give this a try.

Comment: I ended up going here for the Freya ISO `elementaryos-0.3.2-stable-amd64.20151209.iso`, and verified it with the SHA256 checksum from above. Thanks for hosting these.

Comment: I have created a mirror of the images hosted by @user22600 on my [pCloud account](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=kZpd03kZCrpq0zXzfuSg3sGCir6JFY8vdb9k).

Answer (score 0):

All of the versions are online at: http://osarchive.sda1.eu/elementary-os (as I just noticed the post above already says)

Comment: You should be able to delete your own answer, which would be useful since, as you say, it duplicates another.