# how to install on a MacMini 1.1

Tags: kernel

Every time I try to run the installer I get the following message:-

**"This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot – please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU"**

Is there a 32 bit version of the OS I can download?

Answer (score 0):

My recollection is that from Loki (0.4) on there is only 64 bit ... so you may need to find an older version for 32 bit ... remember not supported

see

Comment: damn where did that link go ... http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/where-can-i-download-older-versions-of-elementary-os/8270#8270