# Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki iso download

Tags: release-loki, download

I want download Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki iso , but can't found link download, who can give me link Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki iso,

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I did found a link but isn't oficial

http://osarchive.sda1.eu/elementary-os

There's more info in the referenced link below

ref: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10473/14940